# Windows : navigate into symlink

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, symlink

I created a symbolic link in windows and it's working fine :)

when I run:

```
Get-ChildItem myLink
```

I get:

```
d-----        MyFolder
```

But when I run:

```
cd myLink
```

It shows error of null exception

I want to run a solution in this path

```
myLink\MyFolder\mySolution.sln
```

How can I run it?
Tnx.

Comment: How did you create the symlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
New-Item -Path $newFolder  -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value $oldFolder -Force
```

Using `mklink` works fine:

```
mklink /d $newFolder $oldFolder
```